# Elasticsearch with ruby and searchkick with all fited params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I use gem searchkick for rails to search with elastic search, i have problem with finding elements with few ids.

I have model/db with:
product_id | vendor_id | target
1   | 1 | test1
1   | 2 | test12
2   | 2 | test23
2   | 3 | test23
1   | 4 | test14

How can i get product id with vendor `id 1 AND 2, Or 1 Or 2` ? I need to construct "best fited product"
when i use standart search its return all fited params like

```
Info.search("*", where: { vendor_id: [1,2] }
```

It returns vendor with id 1 OR 2, but how search to get vendors witch have both ids ?

Answer (score 0):

With search kick when you need to be more granular than the standard queries, you can declare your Elasticsearch body directly:

So you can try something like

```
Info.search( body: {query: {bool: {filter: [{match: { vendor_id: { query: "1 2", operator: "and"}}}]}}})
```